# matrices and inverses help

Tags: matrices

in matrix multiplication  if $AB=I$, do $A$ and $B$ need to be inverses of each other? Can $BA$ not equal I for the same two matrices?

Comment: What if your matrices aren't square?

Comment: yes Matrices A and B needs to be inverse of each other for this fact to hold $AB=BA= I$ since we know that $AB \not=BA$

Answer (score 0):

IF Both A and B are n by n matrices then the following holds:
$$AB=I_n=BA$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the multiplicative property of determinants $detAB=detAdetB=detI$

$detI\neq 0 \implies detA\neq 0 $  and $detB\neq0$

As the determinants for $A$ and $B$ are non zero then they are not singular hence inverse exist.

$AB=I$ now multiply on the right by $B^{-1}$

$\begin{align}
ABB^{-1}&=IB^{-1}\\
AI&=B^{-1}\\
A&=B^{-1}
\end{align}$

A similar thing can be done by multiplying by $A^{-1}$ on the left to give $B=A^{-1}$

Comment: May be  $B^{-1}$ does not exist at all !!

Comment: @Nizar Good point hadn't considered that.